why do rsync-style temp files like "cam1111.jpg.OEXEL2" appear when I kill gstreamer?
I'm working on checking if gstreamer pipeline write image to the filesystem.
It's working on

Gstreamer 1.0
Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Docker version 25.0.4
docker-compose version 1.29.2
Python 3.10

These Gstreamer and Python process is working inside docker container.
It gets data from rtspsrc and write jpeg image to the filesystem.
Python process rapidly request to gstreamer to change its writing file name
to save real time .jpg images.
Pipeline's Bin is like this.
(I wrote code with python binding but actual connection between elements is same.)

rtspsrc
rtph264depay
h264parse
avdec_h264
videoconvert
videoscale
videorate
appsink      -> 'new-sample' callback  ,'need-data' callback
appsrc       -> 'enough-data' callback
videoconvert
queue
cairooverlay -> 'draw' callback
jpegenc
multifilesink

I omitted several options of elements.
If it matters please comment.
It can see properly saved .jpg files with expected file name.
But I can see the file extension never faced before.
With command ls -al
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 root   73241  March 15 18:18 cam1111.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 user1 root   73297  March 14 12:11 cam1111.jpg.OEXEL2

What is .OEXEL2 file extension and why is it created?
I googled but couldn't find any posts mentioning .OEXEL2
I am expecting to get an answer for definition of .OEXEL2 and why is it created.
I did stat {filename} Linux command and result is like this.
File: cam1111.jpg.OEXEL2
  Size: 73297           Blocks: 144        IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10302h/66306d   Inode: 105939386   Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  infer1)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2024-03-14 13:53:21.011363940 +0900
Modify: 2024-03-14 12:11:41.013794008 +0900
Change: 2024-03-14 12:11:41.013794008 +0900
 Birth: 2024-03-14 12:11:41.013794008 +0900

The result of file cam1111.jpg.OEXEL2 is like this.
cam1111.jpg.OEXEL2: JPEG image data, baseline, precision 8, 1920x1080, components 3


might be rsync junk.

The Linux command for identifying what's in a file is file, not stat.

Have you grepped your own project to see if that string "OEXEL2" appears anywhere?

@jpa I searched whole project file but couldn't grep any including "OEXEL2".

@jasonharper Thanks, I will supplement the question.

Have you tried if this happens every time you run the application, or it happened only once?

@jpa It happens evert time I run the application.

@ChristophRackwitz I checked rsync man page and related posts at the stack exchange.
link.
It seems it might be rsync temp file as you mentioned.
I am definitely seeing this kind of files only when I raise KeyboardInterrupt by ctrl+c or kill -9 {the application's pid}.
I am not sure but I think I saw extension name like 'GV4H3' before.

I'm not completely convinced that it's rsync because I only know rsync temp files to be prepended by a . and this here isn't. did you rename the file to remove the leading dot?

No, I didn't rename it manually by CLI.

it might actually be something that gstreamer itself does... I wouldn't know, don't know its innards.
